# Error con arreglo dinamico en ordenamiento burbuja recursivo C

Tags: array, c, ordenamiento

Necesito ayuda para mi codigo, tengo que llenar un vector gigante con numeros aleatorios y ordenarlos con algoritmo burbuja recursivo, sin embargo aunque compila , no me arroja ningun resultadoy no imprime nada, parece que el error es cuando le paso el vector binario a la funcion burbuja, pero nose como solucionarlo, ayuda

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {
//defino tamano del vector
long int TAMA=500000, i;
//creo vector dinamico para poner muchisimos digitos
long int *listamillones;
//reservo memoria
listamillones =  malloc( TAMA *sizeof (long int));
//lleno el vector con numeros aleatorios
for (i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++){
    listamillones[i] = rand()%2000000;}
//le doy a la funcion el vector con datos y tamaño

burbujarecursivo (listamillones , TAMA);

//imprimo vector (en realidad no lo hace)
for (i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++){
    printf ("%ld   " , listamillones[i]);
}


return 0;
}
//hago el cambio
void cambio (long int *arreglo ,long int i ,long int j){
    int auxiliar;
    auxiliar = arreglo[i] ;
    arreglo[i] = arreglo[j] ;
    arreglo[j]=auxiliar;
}

void burbujarecursivo (long int *arreglo , long int total){
    long int i;
    int hubocambio=0;
    for (i=0 ; i<total ; i++){
       if (arreglo[i] > arreglo[i+1]){
           hubocambio=1;
           cambio (arreglo , i , i+1);
            }
        }
//si hay tan solo un cambio , el valor es uno, y vuelve a llamarse hasta que no hayan cambios
       if (hubocambio==1)
          burbujarecursivo (arreglo ,total-1);

}```
````

Comment: Más allá de que no hayas declarado las funciones o que no incluyas la cabecera `stdio.h` el código sí funciona. Solo que hiciste la animalada de ordenar 500000 elementos con un algoritmo ineficiente y además los imprimes a la consola, cosa que también es más ineficiente de lo que sería escribirlo a un archivo.

Comment: [Compruébalo tu mismo](https://tio.run/##hVLBboMwDL3nK6xOlUhpJ9iOlEr9gGmX3aYeQqDUKJApQDWt6q@PJaFAaA@zFMl5jt97NvBNznnXPWHFRZtmsK2bFOXzaUdmkMBkjjVYZgYhWDVQMqw8ChdChKxyMNDH/m0fh0GwBowceCWwbliJQiNZbSruHWLQXDrnniWAVY0/mTyCNxBQqnuOUoGHcQAR4Na@04nv0wsBHTPGTzxoUsWq1KPLl8BGRK6EJK1K2oKpjLeqxrPUEjMna2vgf7UvpV1pg4ulSAEWuu9en1o9orKmVRX06meJKXBWJii9aTdMqSwXUlMMEMJ6zIuboslZ@40CmYosMtz0pDcKM/atNgFTtbivFod4ohz83a/o0Sk4VhvZMDF8gtF/NFo@tYnsJ46DHp0t1rbPNmv69GKdAXbTNH54mJ6ZcOjDyC304MijLaM5fkhnz@BKpszVd4jjkDotj3/QKGGH2RgFcu26X34ULK@7zfvrHw).

Comment: jaja si la cabezera no la copie pero si la puse en el codigo, la idea era ver el tiempo de ejecucion de distintos algoritmos, (trabajo universitario) primero es el burbuja recursivo, de ahi devo seguir intentandolo con shellsort, quicksort y mergesort, asi que es muy probable que vuelva a preguntar jajaja. al final despues de varias modificaciones, me di cuenta que el problema era el orden de las posiciones del codigo, aunque supongo que el printf si se lo sacare, primero tenia que ir cambio, despues , burbuja recursivo, y al final las llamadas en el main.

Comment: Sugiero que pruebes el código con menos elementos antes de preguntar de nuevo. Las computadoras son muy buenas haciendo cálculos pero tampoco hacen milagros.

Comment: no es como que haya puesto los 500 mil datos por gusto, es una tarea donde tengo que evaluar distintos tipos de ordenamiento, con distintas cantidades de datos, siendo el maximo 10 millones, asi con la cantidad de elementos y tiempo empleado hacer una gradica en exel y comparar, y si , primero lo compilo con pocos datos y de ahi lo pruebo con mas, este pedi ayuda porque ni con 100 datos me compilaba (aunque ya identifique los errores)